Parallelizing 3D Point Cloud Transformation Using OpenMP Without Additional Memory Allocation
I'm working on a C program that applies a linear transformation to a 3D point cloud using a transformation matrix T. Each point is a row in an n×3 matrix, and T is a 3×3 matrix. My goal is to update the point cloud in place, but I'm encountering issues with dependencies during the parallel update. I want to avoid allocating an additional matrix for the results due to memory constraints.
Here's the relevant part of the code:
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int num_of_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    int points[n][3], T[3][3], i, j, k;
    srand(time(NULL));

    omp_set_num_threads(num_of_threads);
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            T[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    // Initialize points
    #pragma omp parallel for collapse(2)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            points[i][j] = rand() % 1000;
        }
    }

    // Apply transformation
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k, temp)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            int temp = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                temp += points[i][k] * T[j][k];
            }
            points[i][j] = temp; // Direct update introduces data dependency issues
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


Challenges:
Directly updating points[i][j] leads to data dependency issues because transformations of different coordinates are not independent.
Using a critical section (which I tried but omitted here for brevity) severely impacts performance and doesn't solve the problem of reading from and writing to the same location.
Question:
Is there a smarter way to parallelize this operation without allocating additional memory for the transformed points? I am specifically looking for a method to manage dependencies efficiently while utilizing OpenMP.
--------CODE EDIT---------
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

double my_rand(long *seed)
{
    long next_rnd = (1366 * (*seed) + 150889) % 714025;
    *seed = next_rnd;
    return ((double)next_rnd / (double)714025);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int num_of_threads = atoi(argv[1]);
    int n = atoi(argv[2]);
    int T[3][3], i, j, k;
    double points[n][3];
    long seed;
    srand(time(NULL));

    omp_set_num_threads(num_of_threads);
    // matrix T
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            T[i][j] = rand() % 100;
        }
    }

    // points
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) private(i, j, seed) shared(points,n)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            seed = omp_get_thread_num() + 123456789;
            points[i][j] = my_rand(&seed);
        }
    }

//  transformation
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k) shared(points, n)
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double temp[3] = {0, 0, 0}; // temporary local storage for transformed coordinates; private by default
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                temp[j] += points[i][k] * T[j][k];
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            points[i][j] = temp[j]; // write transformed points back to points array
        }
    }

    return 0;
}



Are you sure it isn't rand() causing the issue? rand() doesn't parallelize in this way. You'd need to make your own substitute. Don't you need private i and j in the middle loop?

Hello, I see so rand has one global seed; i have edited the code is this solution better now?

You have modified your code, which looks ok now, right?

You use the same seed in each iteration so results should be the same. Not very "random" ;) . Besides calling omp_get_thread_num in a hot loop that way is not very efficient either. You should move it in the beginning of a  #pragma parallel section (so after spawning threads) and then use #pragma omp for inside it (so to share the work between threads).

Note that array of structure (or array of a fixed number of items which is not a power of two or used separately) are not very efficient. This can often prevent SIMD optimization by compilers. It is often better to use structure of arrays, especially here I think. This means a points[3][n] array. Using SIMD units is critical on modern processors since they have generally 8-16 lanes able to compute 4-8 times more items than scalar codes in the same time (thanks to 1-2 SIMD units). This means a 4-8 times faster code. The speed-up can typically be comparable to using multiple cores.

I expect this (updated) code to be memory-bound once vectorized properly (by the compiler possibly after changing the layout) or once parallelized. Memory bound code do not scale (since the shared RAM is the limit and not the CPU cores). One solution to avoid this problem is to merge loop and consume data where there are produced. Put it shortly : increase temporal locality.

Your basic question is unsolvable: there are no points you can update because the old value of any point is still used by other point computations.
So if you don't have a temporary vector, you will always get some propagation effect.
If you can live with a minimal difference between your sequential & parallel algorithm, you can apply a red-black coloring to your points: first update all red points in parallel, then update all black points in parallel. The red points will be correct, and the black ones will be half an iteration off. EDIT with your three-point dependency you probably need three colors.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see any problematic dependency in OPs code. The outer loop is distributed among threads. For each point i a thread reads all three components three times and then updates them afterward. No other thread is accessing that point i.

@paleonix Hm. Strictly speaking your right. However, each [i][j] is a sum of 3 [i][k], so for each i you need a private temp vector of length 3. Of course, you actually only need such a tmp vector per thread, not per i. But I'm not sure how to code that efficiently. Food for thought.

So are we agreeing that there is no race condition, i.e. "the old value of any point is still used by other point computations." is plain wrong? The point computations are independent and trivially parallel. So what exactly are you thinking about? temp lives on the stack so I don't see a problem with it being per point and not per thread. In terms of optimization I would rather question if T is causing some false sharing and should be firstprivate.
